# PineScript Tradingview: % change comparative chart in the display window

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to write a code in pinescript to plot multiple equities on one window. I have written something like below.

```
indicator("My script", overlay = true, shorttitle='Comparitive RS')
nifty = request.security("NIFTY", timeframe.period, close)
plot(nifty, title = "NIFTY", linewidth = 2)

banknifty = request.security("BANKNIFTY", timeframe.period, close)
plot(banknifty, title = "BANKNIFTY", linewidth = 1)

FINnifty = request.security("CNXFINANCE", timeframe.period, close)
plot(FINnifty, title = "FINnifty", linewidth = 1)

cnxpharma = request.security("CNXPHARMA", timeframe.period, close)
plot(cnxpharma, title = "CNXPHARMA", linewidth = 1)
```

It is giving me the output something like below.

[image: chart output]

However, I want something like this:

[image: desired chart]

Wherein the Y Axis is in % format and start period for the yaxis is 1st bar itself.

Let me know if somebody could help me with this.

I have already tried the code written above and 1st image in the output. whereas i want something like 2nd image as output.